# How do I handling exceptions with python generators using spaCy

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator, spacy

I am using the spacy language.pipe method to process texts as a stream, and yield Doc objects in order. (https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe).

This method is faster than processing files one by one and takes a generator object as input.

If the system hits a "bad file" I want to ensure that I can identify it. However, I am not sure how to achieve this with Python generators. What is the best approach for ensuring I capture the error? I don't currently have a file to cause an error but will likely find one in production.

I am using spaCy version 2.1 and Python 3.6.3

```
import os
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

def genenerator():
    path = "C:/Temp/tmp/" #place any text files here for testing

    try:
        for root, _, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
            for name in files:
                with open(os.path.join(root, name), 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as inputFileStream:
                    docText = inputFileStream.read()
                yield (docText, name)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error opening document. Doc name: {}'.format(os.path.join(root, name)), str(e))

def processfiles():
    try:
        for doc, file in nlp.pipe(genenerator(), as_tuples = True, batch_size=1000):
            print (file)

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error processing file: {}'.format(file), str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processfiles()
```

Edit - I have attempted to better explain my problem.

The specific thing I need to be able to do is to identify exactly what file caused a problem to spaCy, in particular I want to know exactly what file fails during this statement
    for doc, file in nlp.pipe(genenerator(), as_tuples = True, batch_size=1000):

My assumption is that it could be possible to run into a file that causes spaCy to have an issue during the pipe statement (for example during the tagger or parser processing pipeline).

Originally I was processing the text into spaCy file by file, so if spaCy had a problem then I knew exactly what file caused it. Using a generator this seems to be harder.
I am confident that errors that occur in the generator method itself can be captured, especially taking on board the comments by John Rutledge.

Perhaps a better way to ask the question is how to I handle exception when generators are passed to methods like this. 
My understanding is that the PIPE method will process the generator as a stream.

Comment: "I want to ensure that I can identify it" -- so just let the exception occur naturally.  It sounds as if there's an implicit requirement to let it proceed on subsequent files even if processing fails on one or more files?

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have edited my question adding more information at the bottom to explain my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your main problem is that your try/catch statement will currently halt execution on the first error it encounters. To continue yielding files when an error is encountered you need to place your `try/catch` further down in the for-loop, i.e. you can wrap the `with open` context manager.

Note also that a blanket `try/catch` is considered an anti-pattern in Python, so typically you will want to catch and handle the errors explicitly instead of using the general purpose `Exception`. I included the more explicit `IOerror` and `OSError` as examples.

Lastly, because you can catch the errors in the generator itself the `nlp.pipe` function no longer needs the `as_tuple` param.

```
from pathlib import Path
import spacy


def grab_files(path):
    for path in Path(path).rglob('*'):
        if path.is_file():
            try:
                with open(str(path), 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
                    yield f.read()
            except (OSError, IOError) as err:
                print(f'ERROR: {path}', err)


nlp = spacy.load('en')
for doc in nlp.pipe(grab_files('C:/Temp/tmp/'), batch_size=1000):
    print(doc)  # ... do something with spacy Doc here
```

*Edit - to answer followup question.

Note, you are still reading the contents of the text documents one at a time as you would have without a generator, however doing so via a generator returns an object that defers the execution until after you pass it into the `nlp.pipe` method. SpaCy then processes one batch of the text documents at a time via its internal `util.minibatch` function. That function ends in `yield list(batch)` which executes the code that opens/closes the files (1000 at a time in your case). So as regards any non-SpaCy related errors, i.e. errors associated with the opening/reading of the file, the code I posted should work as is.

However, as it stands, both your `os.walk` and my `Path(path).rglob` are indiscriminately picking up any file in the directory regardless of its filetype. So for example, if there were an `.png` file in your `/tmp` folder then SpaCy would raise a `TypeError` during the tokenization process. If you are wanting to capture those kinds of errors then your best bet is to anticipate and avoid them before sending them to SpaCy, e.g., by amending your code with a whitelist that only allows certain file extensions (`.rglob('*.txt')`).

If you are working on a project that for some reason or another cannot afford to be interrupted by an error, no matter the cost. And supposing you absolutely needed to know at which stage of the pipeline the error occurred, then one approach might be to create a custom pipeline component for each default SpaCy pipeline component (Tagger, DependencyParser, etc) you intend to use. You would then need to wrap said components in the blanket error handling/logging logic. Having done that you could then process your files using your completely custom pipeline. But, unless there is a gun pointed at your head I would not recommend it. Much better would be to anticipate the errors you expect to occur and handle them inside your generator. Perhaps someone with better knowledge of SpaCy's internals will have a better suggestion though.

Comment: John, This is really useful information and I have taken on board the blanket try/catch comment and the improved exception handling information you have provided so thanks for that.
I don't think I explained my issue correctly so I have added further information to the original question with a new section in the Edit. Any advice you are able to offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for this comment and your edit. On reflection now that I understand this issue better I think this was very useful to my understanding. I am tempted to modify spaCy to add more error handling but for now I will try and trap any potential errors in the generator